# Codeigniter 3.0: how can I define these routes?

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, codeigniter-3

I had some troubles with CodeIgniter routing:
I want to build a site for showing some products, and need to build a URL follow the rule:

`http://localhost/testsite/category-name/product-name/id.html` or `http://localhost/testsite/pro-id/category-name/sub-category-name1/.../product-name.html`, 
with "category-name","sub-category-name1", "sub-category-name2"...,"product-name", and "id" were loaded dynamic from database.

How can I config the route value for this one?
I've tried with some cases but it's not working:

```
$route['pro-(:num)/(:any).html'] = 'product/detail?pid=$1';
$route['(:any)/(:num)'] = 'product/detail?pid=$1';
```

Many thanks for any helps!

Thanks @Bira for your support, but the problem was still there :)

Here is the content of my 'routes.php'

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'product';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
$route['home.html'] = 'product/index';
$route['pro-(:num)/(.+).html'] = 'product/detail?pid=$1';
$route['(:any)/(:any)/(:num).html'] = 'product/detail?pid=$3';
```

And the content of .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^home.html  index.php/product/index
RewriteRule ^pro-([0-9]+)/(.*).html  index.php/product/detail?pid=$1
RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Za-z]+)/([0-9A-Za-z]+)/([0-9]+).html  index.php/product/detail?pid=$3
```

And ... only one URL is working "http://localhost/testsite/home.html" (the first rule). Other rules will return error: 404 Page Not Found (Ex: "http://localhost/testsite/pro-3/category-name/product-name.html")

Here is my test controller class:

```
class Product extends CI_Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('products');
    }
    public function detail()
    {
        $pid = $_GET['pid'];
        $data['pid'] = $pid;
        $this->load->view('product_detail', $data);
    }
}
```

Thanks you so much for any supports, I'm just a newbie on CI :)

Comment: Thanks you, @Sparky, for making my question more clearly :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure Apache .htaccess is enabled.
Make sure the Apache module mod_rewrite is enabled.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'm sure that the .htaccess is enabled and locate in root folder, mod_rewrite is enabled too. I'm still running my old website with rewritten URL, just want to upgrade the old source-code with CI framework, but I had a trouble at the beginning, so sad :( .

Comment: dont worry for the next step..
http://localhost/testsite/category-name/product-name/id.html
    $route['(:any)/:any)/(:num).html'] = 'product/detail?pid=$1';
maintain the number of slashes between URLs

Answer (score 1):

Remove `pid=$1` from your route rules. It will work. See below code.

```
$route['pro-(:num)/(:any).html'] = 'product/detail';
$route['(:any)/(:num)'] = 'product/detail';
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes, it worked but I don't know how to get the 'pid' value. I need this 'id' for query data from db :)

Comment: use `$this->input->get('pid');` and pass pid in querystring

Comment: :), yeah...it worked for "http://localhost/testsite/pro-1/sdasd/sdasdasd/sdasdasd.html?pid=3" but not for "http://localhost/testsite/pro-3/sdasd/sdasdasd/sdasdasd.html". Anyway, I have some ideas for this problem from your support, thank you so much.